# How to handle the ratings within bubble rating widget with in Tripadvisor?

Tags: java, selenium, tripadvisor

I hava a scenario in which i need to click fifth bubble of bubble rating widget within [tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.in/UserReviewEdit-g641714-d1156207-Club_Mahindra_Madikeri_Coorg-Madikeri_Kodagu_Coorg_Karnataka.html)

The HTML code is:

```
<span id="bubble_rating" class="ui_bubble_rating fl bubble_10" data-value="1" onclick="ta.userreview.common.trackFieldFocus(this); ">
<img src="https://static.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif" alt="Roll over, then click to rate">
</span>
```

I am trying with below code snippet:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='bubble_rating']"));
action.moveToElement(element).perform();
```

This code hovers only first 3 bubbles and rest 4th,5th are not being clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click for all the **5** star ratings within the *Bubble Rating* widget in https://www.tripadvisor.in/ using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.in/UserReviewEdit-g641714-d1156207-Club_Mahindra_Madikeri_Coorg-Madikeri_Kodagu_Coorg_Karnataka.html]");
  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span#bubble_rating"))), 50, 0).click().build().perform();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.in/UserReviewEdit-g641714-d1156207-Club_Mahindra_Madikeri_Coorg-Madikeri_Kodagu_Coorg_Karnataka.html]");
  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@id='bubble_rating']"))), 50, 0).click().build().perform();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: bubble_rating_widget]